# PostgreSQL 9.5, getting "cached plan must not change result type" error

Tags: postgresql, cursors, postgresql-9.5, delphi

I had a really odd and unexpected behaviour in PostgreSQL. Debugging I found that the problem only occurred while including `CREATE TEMP TABLE ...` inside a function, and by using an alternative (in this case, I resorted to an array) the error would be gone. Perhaps any one experienced a similar error or knows what this error relates to? I might need to create temporary tables in functions sooner or later.

I'm porting an old Delphi XE6 program from a legacy proprietary database to PostgreSQL, changing the TxxTable components (proprietary) to TFDTable ones (FireDAC) pointing to a copy of the database in PostgreSQL 9.5.

Things were working peachy until I created this plpgsql function that inserts and updates some data here and there. I ran the function via `PGConnection.ExecSQLScalar('SELECT do_stuff(:id)', FID);`, where `PGConnection` is my TFDConnection to PostgreSQL (same where I have many other tables open and working well), `do_stuff` is the function in question, and `FID` is an ID I send as a parameter. The function runs well, as it does when running it from PgAdmin, but the connection becomes unstable as any *already open* table afterwards trying to do anything (insert/edit/move) will raise the following error:

> ERROR:  cached plan must not change result type
>   STATEMENT:  FETCH FORWARD 50 FROM "357STM"`

FireDAC normally opens tables and queries using cursors:

> LOG:  execute 358STM: DECLARE "357STM" CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR SELECT * 
>  FROM table

If I execute `do_stuff(:id)` via an TFDQuery component, the function itself fails (FireDAC executes it as a cursor), raising the same error stated above.

After tearing my hear out debugging, I realised that the only way to avoid the error was avoid creating any temporary tables inside the function. Whereas creating the function as `CREATE TEMP TABLE tbl ON COMMIT DROP AS SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE ....` or as `CREATE TEMP TABLE tbl (id int, value text);` the error was raised. Without `CREATE TEMP TABLE`, no errors raised.

Any clues will be highly appreciated!

Comment: A complete function definition would be of help. A minimal example to reproduce the problem. Since a temp table created with `ON COMMIT DROP` is dropped at the end of the *transaction*, while an SQL cursor `WITH HOLD` is retained until the end of the *session*, I am not surprised you run into problems. Odd, though, that you see the same problem for a temp table without `ON COMMIT DROP` ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I'll work on a script to try and reproduce the error, and update the question.

Answer (score 3):

FireDAC FDQuery.

Cursor kind in fetch options was set to `ckAutomatic`. I changed it to `ckDefault` and it works now.

Comment: Can you [edit] some more detail into your answer to explain how this solves the problem as stated in the question?